# Error when trying to install imblearn package

Tags: scikit-learn, imbalanced-data, imblearn

After:

```
pip install imblearn
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements imblearn (from version: none).
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

They switched to using `imbalanced-learn`. [See their old PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/imblearn/).

So you'll want to use:

```sh
pip install imbalanced-learn
```

Or

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
```

Comment: Thanks. But this gave me the same results

Comment: Interesting. That worked for me. To help further, I’d need to know more details about your Python installation and whether you have the right versions of dependencies. Can you check the install page and confirm your versions of the dependencies are up to date: https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/ And what Python version do you have?

Comment: Solved. It was a problem with the proxy. It is a secured server. Thanks!